# Is it possible to show the path of eclipse.exe in the Title?

Tags: eclipse

I know to show workspace in the Title I need to use `-showLocation` option in `eclipse.ini` file.

What I also want to show is the path of eclipse.exe in the Title.

So if I am running eclipse.exe from C:\Programs\Eclipse1 folder then Title would show `C:\Programs\Eclipse1`.

And if I am running eclipse.exe from C:\Programs\Eclipse2 folder then Title would show `C:\Programs\Eclipse2`.

Is it possible? If yes please tell me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for Eclipse.

The code responsible for setting the title is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchWindowAdvisor`.